# Azure IoT - What if both server and client are changing device twin properties?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have an Azure IoT solution that uses the Remote Monitoring Accelerator. Both the server (remote monitoring web) and client (device) are changing the device twin properties. Sometimes those properties get into the "syncing" state and don't seem to get out of it.

So what are the rules for who has the authority to change device twin properties and when?

I use the IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendReportedState() function to change properties from the device side, btw.

Comment: The server-side should (and in fact can) only update the Desired properties. The client always only the Reported properties.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, sorry. Yes, if the server initiates a property change, it will update a desired property and then the client will send back IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendReportedState() with that change stating - yes, I did that change. And if the CLIENT initiates a property change, it will call the same function - IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendReportedState() with a totally new value for the property. The problem is that that works sometimes and sometimes not - the property ends up in a "synching" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure IoT Device Twin represents a lightweight generic data (state) model for disconnectable distributed *ends* such as a *device-facing end* and *service-facing end*. The Device Twin has a support for creating a "shadow copy" between those ends in the transitions manner. Basically, each *end* has ownership for writing (or updating) its property, which the other *end* is notified for this changes.

[image]

Based on this notifications, versioning and device twin metadata, the state can be transited from one *end* to other one in the reliable manner. Note, that the lightweight state machine must be implemented at the each end such as a device and backend triggered by the notification changes.

The above picture is from document [Device twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#device-twins), where is described this model in the detail.

**Update:**

The following screen snippet is an example of the sequence diagram for transition states between the Device and Back-end using a Device Twin properties:

[image]

In the above example, this distributed state machine handles a transmission state from *inprocess, ack, done, null* between the Device and Back-end. Similar can be created the transitions for instance: *inprocess, nack, null*, between the Back-end and Device, for disconnected device, etc.

This example used an additional property such as a *status* to indicate that the property *Config* is in the transition state, but can be added more, for instance, original value, version, etc. which they help to recover state, etc.

Comment: I understand but how do I get a property out of the "syncing" state? That CAN happen, but not always, when the client sets a reported property that's not the same as the desired property from the server - but it's because in that case the client wants to report a property change (due to someone walking into the room and changing something on the device).

Comment: I'm only calling the IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SendReportedState() function from the device client. Perhaps that isn't enough and that's why my properties sometimes end up in a "synced" state??

Comment: ...if not, which functions do I have to call and/or which callbacks do I have to register? I just want to be able to let the device be able to originate property changes as well as the back-end.

Comment: **On the device side**, you should also set the callback for handling a notification changes at the desired state (back-end), such as the function IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetDeviceTwinCallback. **On the back-end side**, you should setup a message routing in the Azure IoT Hub for *Data source  = TwinChangeEvents* to push a notification message to the custom endpoint for handling a transition state on the desired properties based on the reported changes.

Comment: Thank you. I'm already calling IoTHubDeviceClient_LL_SetDeviceTwinCallback(). I'll looking into this message routing. I haven't really done that. I assume that this could get me pointed in the right direction? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c