# Azure IoT device needs to get desired properties from while it was offline

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm developing an Azure IoT application. All my devices are connected to an Azure IoT Hub and use device twins. My problem is this:

If a device goes offline and then my backend web application causes changes to the device's desired twin properties, the device doesn't seem to get that info later when it reboots.

How can the device get this when rebooting? When the device reboots, I want it to retrieve all the desired property notifications that came while it was offline. Is this possible and if so, what are the ways to do it?

Comment: have a look at again my answer to you about the synchronizing the distributed state between the real device and back-end, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288383/azure-iot-what-if-both-server-and-client-are-changing-device-twin-properties In the case of restarting (rebooting), the device should read all device desired properties and walked through them for their synchronizing in the manner of the transition state.

Comment: Yes, but when the device gets the desired properties after rebooting, I believe it doesn't get the metadata and therefore can't know which of the desired properties have newer timestamps than the reported ones.

Comment: after the device is connected to the Azure IoT Hub, the device can get the desired properties from the IoT Hub. Each desired property should be represented some state object with details about the transitions. This details will actually described the status of the state transition. Every change made on the ends such as at the device and back-end must go through transitions, that why we have the reported and desired properties.

Comment: Hmm, I believe I may have figured out my problem. In my solution, when my backend gets a notification of a reported property change, it does NOT change the equivalent desired property. Is this incorrect behaviour? (Btw. I do have a web application that reads from both desired and reported properties and, for each property, displays the newer one, using the metadata.)

Comment: my sequence diagram described this distributed dis-connectabled state machine where each transition must be well described in the reported and desired properties. If the process of the transition is broken (disconnected, etc.), based on the last transition state in the reported and desired properties can be synchronized and continue to the finally state such as the reported and desired properties are the same.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but is it a general rule that if a device changes a reported property, the back-end should also change the corresponding desired property?

Comment: I do recommend to read the AWS IoT Device Shadows https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html The Azure IoT Hub *Device Twins* has been introduced after the *Device Shadows* and their concept is very generic (useful for IoT Edge) without any built-in synchronization feature.

Comment: Ok, but once again - is it a general rule that if a device changes a reported property, the back-end should also change the corresponding desired property?

Comment: I do recommend to read generic documents for distributed state machines, their patterns, state transmissions from disconnectabled ends, statuses, etc. The concept of the device twins allows to built the reliable device change state over the internet using the reported properties (such as the real device) and desired properties (such as a shadow/twin shared device) persisted on the cloud.  Some principles can be found in the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-firmware-update

Comment: It's upto the backend service to take action on desired property based on reported property. Either you delete the desired property as the device has attained it's state or keep it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregating the comments an convert them to an answer:

**@Roman Kiss**

"In the case of restarting (rebooting), the device should read all device desired properties and walked through them for their synchronizing in the manner of the transition state... after the device is connected to the Azure IoT Hub, the device can get the desired properties from the IoT Hub. Each desired property should be represented some state object with details about the transitions. This details will actually described the status of the state transition. Every change made on the ends such as at the device and back-end must go through transitions, that why we have the reported and desired properties... my sequence diagram described this distributed dis-connectabled state machine where each transition must be well described in the reported and desired properties. If the process of the transition is broken (disconnected, etc.), based on the last transition state in the reported and desired properties can be synchronized and continue to the finally state such as the reported and desired properties are the same."

Related thread: [Azure IoT - What if both server and client are changing device twin properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288383/azure-iot-what-if-both-server-and-client-are-changing-device-twin-properties)

**@iAviator**

"It's up to the backend service to take action on desired property based on reported property. Either you delete the desired property as the device has attained it's state or keep it."

====

Please mark it as answer so others can benefit from your discussion. Thanks!